# CakePHP3: Adding an association in a behavior

Tags: associations, cakephp-3.0, behavior

I'm having a table called settings, which contains typcial setting information, like isactive, activationdate,... which should be associated to a lot of other entities. Now I was wondering if I could put that in a `SettingsBehavior`, so that I just have to load the Behavior in all Table Objects I need it. 
I thought about adding something like this in `SettingsBehavior::beforeFind()`:

```
$event->getSubject()
            ->hasOne('Settings')
            ->setName('Settings')
            ->setForeignKey('parent_id')
            ->setConditions(['Settings.parenttype' => $event->getSubject()->getTable()]);
```

But the Query is already created. At least I'm able to add a setting entity to the entity using the `SettingsBehavior`.
In the Behaviors `initialize()` as far as I know I don't have a reference to the subject.
I then tried to do this in `SettingsBehavior::beforeFind()`:

```
$query->leftJoin('Settings', [
                $event->getSubject()->getAlias() . '.id = Settings.parent_id',
                'Settings.parenttype' => 'users'
            ]);
```

But it also didn't add a setting to my found entity. Does anyone have tried something similiar, or has an idea how to do this? Maybe I'm even wrong trying to do something like this, through a behavior?
Thank you!

Comment: Ok, playing round a bit, I found out, that the following code in `SettingsBehavior::beforeFind()` would work: `$event->getSubject()
            ->hasOne('Settings')
            ->setName('Settings')
            ->setForeignKey('parent_id')
            ->setConditions(['Settings.parenttype' => $event->getSubject()->getTable()]);
        $query->contain(['Settings']);` My entity now contains a setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table (subject as you called it) that a behavior is being attached to, is injected via the behaviors constructor, and stored in the `_table` property, which you can use in the `initialize()` method.

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    // ...
    $this->_table->hasOne('Settings', /* ... */);
}
```

You can then contain or join the association in the behaviors `beforeFind()` callback.

```
public function beforeFind(Event $event, Query $query, \ArrayObject $options)
{
    // ...
    $query->contain('Settings');
}
```